# SQL Database design - Type table requiring different child tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

First off, I appreciate any help with this.

I am struggling to find the best approach to some database design, and I'm not entirely sure where even to start searching for the type of design I am even after.

In short, we have a bunch of payment method types, for example cash, credit card and paypal. But each of these methods require their own set of parameters both for their setup details (ie information for API details for PayPal) as well as transactions for each method requiring a different set of fields - ie. for credit card - we would want the start date, end date, card number etc.. - for paypal we would want the email address and a bunch of other stuff.

Now - I could simply have tables: `payment_method_types`, `payment_methods` and `payments` which have all the required fields to cover all bases - for example `paypal_email_address` field, etc.. but is there a better solution that mimics more of a document-based database whereby you'd just have the relevant fields?

For example the following tables `payment_method_types`, `paypal_payment_methods`, `cash_payment_methods`, `paypal_payments`, `cash_payments` etc.. Which doesn't really seem that nice.

There must be a good solution for what it is I want to achieve? Do I just need to include all possible fields (ie. `paypal_email_address` etc..) and just handle it within my application?

Thanks very much for any input.

Comment: I think I am going for payment_methods, payment_types, payments and then a child payments_paypal table (or paypal_payments) which will hold the paypal-specifics of the payment (and likewise for credit card etc..). And then using a concern to deal with the shared logic.

Anyone any thoughts for the naming of the table/model? I'd like to keep it plural in order to keep it the same as my other tables - but having the payments_/Payments prefix is also useful - and payments_paypals doesn't really found/look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be downvoted by that by relational guys :), but you can store this type of information in [JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) (there's good support of JSON in PostgreSQL version 9.3) or [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) columns, it could be good mix of relational database and noSQL style.

You can store common fields like Amount, Date, Currency and so on in typed columns and have one column of type JSON/hstore to store additional details like card number. So your data could look like:

```
Type          Date         Amount  Currency  Additional
Credit Card   2013-08-01     15.1  EUR       {Card Number: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"}
PayPal        2013-07-02    103.8  USD       {Email: "client@company.com"}
```

or hstore:

```
Type          Date         Amount  Currency  Additional
Credit Card   2013-08-01     15.1  EUR       Card Number => "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
PayPal        2013-07-02    103.8  USD       Email => "client@company.com"
```

Or you can create subtables for additional information - so you store common data in table `Payments` and store all additional info in `PaymentsPayPal`, `PaymentsCreditCard` and so on.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that will cost you a lot to retrieve statistics from your server. And every one loves statistics with payments. Bonus points to managers.

Comment: @fotanus it could be possible to store only additional fields in JSON/hstore and main fields in child table - every payment have amount, date, currency - these fields goes into typed columns, additional information goes into JSON.

Comment: @RomanPekar That, with some caution, would do greatly. Just need to be extra-careful to avoid database changes on the future.

Answer (score 1):

This answer can be very complex, but I will go with something simple to inspire only. Something like

```
CreditCardPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PaymentType
  def paypal_some_kind_of_id
    2
  end
end

PaypalPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PaymentType
  def paypal_some_kind_of_id
    1
  end
end
```

Then, whenever dealing with payments, write only one method, and make sure the method works with both a `PaypalPayment` and a `CreditCardPayment` object. Methods that are equal for all classes can go within the PaymentType module, to keep your code dry.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I assume you mean we'd just have the tables: payment_types, payment_methods and payments - and we are basically dealing with it in-app and using a concern for the shared code? I will keep that in mind if there isn't a viable alternative. Thanks again.